# Indirect return of all elements in an array

Tags: bash, array

The Bash man page describes use of `${!a}` to return the contents of the variable whose name is the contents of `a` (a level of indirection).

I'd like to know how to return all elements in an array using this, i.e.,

```
a=(one two three)
echo ${a[*]}
```

returns

```
one two three
```

I would like for:

```
b=a
echo ${!b[*]}
```

to return the same.  Unfortunately, it doesn't, but returns `0` instead.

**Update**

Given the replies, I now realise that my example was too simple, since of course, something like:

```
b=("${a[@]}")
```

Will achieve exactly what I said I needed.

So, here's what I was *trying* to do:

```
LIST_lys=(lys1 lys2)
LIST_diaspar=(diaspar1 diaspar2)

whichone=$1   # 'lys' or 'diaspar'

_LIST=LIST_$whichone
LIST=${!_LIST[*]}
```

Of course, carefully reading the Bash man page shows that this won't work as expected because the last line simply returns the indices of the "array" `$_LIST` (not an array at all).

In any case, the following should do the job (as pointed out):

```
LIST=($(eval echo \${$_LIST[*]}))
```

or ... (the route that I went, eventually):

```
LIST_lys="lys1 lys2"
...
LIST=(${!_LIST})
```

Assuming, of course, that elements don't contain whitespace.

Comment: Add `[@]` to the pointer `_LIST="LIST_${whichone}[@]"` and then, use `LIST=("${!_LIST}")` to copy the array. It is a good idea to use lower case variable names to avoid conflicts with environment variables (All caps).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the use of indirect reference of bash variable should be treated literally.

Eg. For your original example:

```
a=(one two three)
echo ${a[*]} # one two three
b=a
echo ${!b[*]} # this would not work, because this notation 
              # gives the indices of the variable b which
              # is a string in this case and could be thought
              # as a array that conatins only one element, so
              # we get 0 which means the first element
c='a[*]'
echo ${!c} # this will do exactly what you want in the first
           # place
```

For the last real scenario, I believe the code below would do the work.

```
LIST_lys=(lys1 lys2)
LIST_diaspar=(diaspar1 diaspar2)

whichone=$1   # 'lys' or 'diaspar'

_LIST="LIST_$whichone"[*]
LIST=( "${!_LIST}" ) # Of course for indexed array only 
                     # and not a sparse one
```

It is better to use notation `"${var[@]}"` which avoid messing up with the `$IFS` and parameter expansion. Here is the final code.

```
LIST_lys=(lys1 lys2)
LIST_diaspar=(diaspar1 diaspar2)

whichone=$1   # 'lys' or 'diaspar'

_LIST="LIST_$whichone"[@]
LIST=( "${!_LIST}" ) # Of course for indexed array only 
                     # and not a sparse one
                     # It is essential to have ${!_LIST} quoted
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to copy the elements explicitly. For an indexed array:

```
b=("${a[@]}")
```

For an associative array (note that `a` is the name of the array variable, not a variable whose value is the name of an array variable):

```
typeset -A b
for k in "${!a[@]}"; do b[$k]=${a[$k]}; done
```

If you have the variable name in an array, you can use the element-by-element method with an extra step to retrieve the keys.

```
eval "keys=(\"\${!$name[@]}\")"
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do eval "b[\$k]=\${$name[\$k]}"; done
```

(Warning, the code in this post was typed directly in a browser and not tested.)

Comment: You're quite right, but unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem (my example was too simplistic).  I've provided an update to be more clear on my intention.

Comment: @Eric I think in ksh/bash you need eval at that stage. See my edit.

Comment: +1, but as per your disclaimer, this actually doesn't quite work (the last bit of code), but only needs a few minor adjustments.  Specifically, it should be `\${!$name[@]}` on the first line, so that the first expansion is only of '$name', and the `${!a[@]}` is saved for the eval, and the same thing in the for loop, with `\${$name}`.  The other two backslashes before '$k' aren't strictly necessary there either.

Answer (score 2):

`${!b[*]}` expands to the indices used in array `b`.

What you would like has to be done in two steps, so `eval` will help: `eval echo \${$b[*]}`. (Note the `\` which ensures that the first `$` will pass the first step, the variable expansion, and will be only expanded in the second step by `eval`.)

According to Parameter Expansion `!` is both used for indirect expansion (`{!a}`), Names matching prefix (`${!a*}`) and List of array keys (`${!a[*]}`). Because List of array keys has the same syntax as your intended indirect expansion+array element expansion, the later is not supported as is.

Comment: `${!a}` does expand to the value of the variable whose name is `$a`. This is rather tersely described in the manual, in the parragraph that begins with “If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (`!`), a level of variable indirection is introduced.”

Comment: Yep - @Gilles is right, but @manatwork, on second reading, I noticed that `${!` is kinda ambigious since if it's an array you're dealing with, the behaviour is different.

Comment: @Gilles you are right on that sentence, but sadly it not applies as "The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below." But my reply is certainly an ambiguous mess, so I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

To access arrays indirectly, just add `[@]` to the indirect variable `b=a[@]`.

If this variables are set:

```
a=(one two three)
printf '<%s> ' "${a[@]}"; echo
```

Then, this will work:

```
b="a[@]"
printf '<%s> ' "${!b}"
```

Or simply:

```
echo "${!b}"
```

Such array could be copied as this:

```
newArr=( "${!b}" )
```

And then printed with:

```
declare -p newArr
```

In one script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=(one two three)
echo "original array"
printf '<%s> ' "${a[@]}"; echo

echo "Indirect array with variable b=a[@]"
b="a[@]"
printf '<%s> ' "${!b}"; echo

echo "New array copied in newArr, printed with declare"
newArr=( "${!b}" )
declare -p newArr
```

Of course, all the above will copy a non-sparse array. One in which all indexes have a value.

## sparse arrays

An sparse array is one which may have non-defined elements.
For example `a[8]=1234` defines one element, and, in bash, 0 to 7 do not exist.

To copy such sparse array use this method

1. Print the old array:

   ```
   $ oldarr[8]=1234
   $ declare -p oldarr
   declare -a oldarr=([8]="1234")
   ```
2. Replace the name of the array and capture the string:

   ```
   $ str=$(declare -p oldarr | sed 's/oldarr=/newarr=/')
   ```
3. Eval the string so created, the new array has been defined:

   ```
   $ eval "$str"
   $ declare -p newarr
   declare -a newarr=([8]="1234")
   ```