# How would I create this function to choose a random variable from an array?

Tags: bash, array

Here is my attempt:

```
rand_var() {
printf "%s\n" "${${!1}[RANDOM % ${#${!1}[@]}]}"
}
```

And I run it like this

```
array=("something" "somethingelse" "test")
rand_var array
```

However, it tells me `bad substitution`. I think it may have something to do with the variables and quoting but I can't figure it out, I use `${!1}` so that it acctually uses the contents of the variable and not just `array`. This line has worked before when I specify the variable name instead of `${!1}`.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: [Indirect return of all elements in an array](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20171). The short version is that you can't use indirection that way and probably need `eval`.

Comment: Why not just `printf '%s\n' "${array[RANDOM%${#array[@]}]}"`

Comment: Actually `nm="$1[@]";tmp=("${!nm}");printf "%s\n" "${tmp[RANDOM % ${#tmp[@]}}"` works without eval, but only by copying the array first.

Comment: @cuonglm different variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by copying the array into a local variable, and then selecting from that array:

```
rand_var() {
    local nm="$1[@]"
    local tmp=("${!nm}")
    printf "%s\n" "${tmp[RANDOM % ${#tmp[@]}]}"
}
```

I don't think you can do it otherwise, because you can't indirect to the length of the array. If you passed in the length to the function as well:

```
rand_var_len() {
    local nm="$1[$((RANDOM % $2))]"
    printf "%s\n" "${!nm}"
}
rand_var_len array ${#array[@]}
```

then you could do it without any copying.

To avoid both, you'll need to use one of the `eval`-alikes.